# Crystal 2016 pull from 2 unrelated tables in one report

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have searched and the only answers I found were for cross joining.

I have 3 tables that are related by 1 field only. I'm trying to pull data from 2 tables that are linked to the other table.

The first table contains salesman data IDnumber, name, address, phone number, hire date, wage, etc.

There is a sales table that contains salesmanIDnumber, date of sale, object sold, and price.

There is a purchases table that contains salesmanIDnumber, date of purchase, object purchased, and price.

The date fields in sales and purchases are unrelated. I know the easiest solution would be to have the sales and purchase table combined with a column for buy/sell, but I didn't create the database and I'm working with what I've got. basically I want to pull all purchases or sales by salesmanID in one report.

I have linked the salesman table to the sales table and the purchases table with left outer joins by the salesman ID. What I'm getting in results is cross join with each result from the purchase table displayed once for each result in the sales table, which gives me multiplied results instead of added. for example, 4 sales and 6 purchases would be 10 entries, but I'm getting 24 results.

I tried entering an example but the site stripped the spacing and pushed everything together basically making it unreadable.

how can I get it to show data from both tables independently?
I do have access to create views in the database if that's the best solution, but I'm not proficient at it.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 views (one for sales, the other for purchases), each Grouped By SalesMan.

Since each SalesMan would have only one row in each view, you can join them without record inflation.

Or use a UNION to append Purchase records to Sales Records, taking care of including a 'Type' column ('Sales' as Type, or 'Puurchases' as Type) and/or reverse sign on quantities to allow summarizing things in a logical.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm not sure I completely understand it. Each salesman has 1 row in the salesman table, but multiple rows in the sales and purchases table.